# RequireJS: Local fallback for if CDN fails

Tags: javascript, requirejs, cdn

In my backbone app, I need to provide a fallback for each required file, in the case that the CDN that delivers them fails.

I have tried overwriting `require.onError` like so:

```
require.onError = function (err) {
    if (err.requireType === 'timeout') {
        var url = err.requireModules;

        if (!!~url.indexOf("jquery/"))
            console.warn("CDN timed out, falling back to local jQuery.js")
            require(["libs/jquery"]);
            return;
        if (!!~url.indexOf("jqueryui/"))
            console.warn("CDN timed out, falling back to local jQueryUI.js")
            require(["libs/jqueryui"]);
            return;
        if (!!~url.indexOf("underscore"))
            console.warn("CDN timed out, falling back to local underscore.js")
            require(["libs/underscore"]);
            return;
        if (!!~url.indexOf("backbone"))
            console.warn("CDN timed out, falling back to local backbone.js")
            require(["libs/backbone"]);
            return;
    }
}
```

The problem is that this will asynchronously load the fallback files. I need these files to load in order, just like the original require statement, where I use the `order!` plugin.

With the overridden `onError`: when the CDN fails to load, the fallback load is started, but not waited for. This presents a problem because the scripts are ordered to be loaded based on their dependencies. Here is a look at my original `require` statement, that depends on the CDN:

```
require([
    "order!http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js",
    "order!http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js",
    "order!http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.3.3/underscore-min.js",
    "order!http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.9.2/backbone-min.js",
    "order!utils/date",
    "order!core/core",
    "order!core/errors",
    "order!core/constants"
], function() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Both CDN's are not terrible, they only fail on average once a day for a window of about a minute at most, and are free. Regardless, I feel this is an interesting problem to solve. Always good to have fallbacks even if you have a perfect CDN, to preserve user experience. Can you suggest any other CDNs?

Comment: I understand where you are coming from, but I am not in the position to suggest purchase of anything like this for our company without providing ample proof that I have tried everything to make the current system work. Also, I am interested in any programming feat, and I can see this particular solution being useful to many people, as many developers (freelancers in particular) do not use pay-for CDNs.

Comment: CDN is real cheap now ($2 to $3 per month) ... I am using AccuWebHosting.Com CDN  and never experienced any downtime. Well, if one server fails in CDN, the content is immediately delivered from the closest available next POP ... And there are usually 40 to 50 POPs in a good CDN ...

Comment: I don't understand the consternation over this question.  Popular CDN + fallback is a common scenario, and gives the advantage that many users won't even have to download the JS as it's already cached in their browser.  Regardless, other async loaders DO solve this real world problem.  The OP was just asking how to solve it with requirejs.

Comment: @numbers1311407, this is my stance exactly.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

What version of RequireJS are you using?  It seems you might want to configure jQuery's fallback as a path in your config, then set up jQuery as a dependency on the other modules that need it.  If you're using ~> 2.0, something like (untested):

```
// in your requirejs config
requirejs.config({
    //To get timely, correct error triggers in IE, force a define/shim exports 
    // check.
    enforceDefine: true,
    paths: {
        jquery: [
            'http://somecdn.com/jquery.min', // your cdn
            'lib/jquery' // your fallback
        ],
        jqueryui: "http://somecdn.com/jquery-ui.min.js"
    },
    shim: {
      jqueryui: ['jquery']
    }
});

// then in your requires
require([jquery, jqueryui, foo, bar], function($) {
    // stuff
});
```

They talk about how to do it [in the wiki](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/wiki/Upgrading-to-RequireJS-2.0#wiki-pathsfallbacks).  If you are not using v2.x, there is a method for handling that here too.

If all the modules are configured to specify their own dependencies, you shouldn't need to worry about the `order!` directives either.

Comment: Beat me to the post by 2 minutes, but yes, this is the answer I went with.

Comment: Haha not even.  I think it was about 15 seconds.

Comment: How is this managed once you run the optimiser? Does it add script tags to the html for excluded files?

Comment: @sidonaldson The fallback path exists to deal with potentially unavailable external resources, and AFAIK, [according to the docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#pathnotsupported), the optimizer only works with local resources.  I believe if you wanted to bundle the external resource, you'd download it first.  Anyone correct me if I'm wrong please; I've always preferred solutions like browserify to AMD.

Comment: Have you tested this ? For my config, if the paths are of the form `[CDN, local]`, and the CDN script is not found (Wi-Fi turned off), then those whose `shim.deps` refer to the script seem to run before the local fallback is chosen.: `requirejs.config({
  baseUrl: 'bower_components',
  paths: {
    /* JS */
    'jquery': ['//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min', 'jquery/jquery.min'],
    'bootstrap': 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min'
  },
  shim: {
    'bootstrap': {
      deps: ['jquery']
    }
  }
}
});` gives `Uncaught Error: Bootstrap requires jQuery`

Comment: @DeanRadcliffe Maybe you can't use the `//` notation.  Both examples explicitly declare the protocol.

Comment: can you have multiple fallback steps? and eventually fallback to local?

Comment: @numbers1311407 What is the advantage of browserify, when having cdn fallbacks and using its optimizer?

Answer (score 20):

I have found a solution to the problem provided in RequireJS 2.x.x. There was a demand for this solution, so in turn, RequireJS added a `paths` object to their config. This provides fallback functionality for CDNs, should they fail.

It should also be noted that the `order!` plugin has been deprecated in Require 2.0, so I also needed to make use of the `shim` object to define dependencies. It's actually a pretty interesting idea.

Here is my new require.config:

```
require.config({
    urlArgs: "ts="+new Date().getTime(), // disable caching - remove in production
    paths: {
        jquery: [
            "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min",
            "libs/jquery"
        ],
        jqueryui: [
            "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min",
            "libs/jqueryui"
        ],
        underscore: [
            "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.3.3/underscore-min",
            "libs/underscore"
        ],
        backbone: [
            "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.9.2/backbone-min",
            "libs/backbone"
        ]
    },
    shim: {
        'jqueryui': ['jquery'],
        'underscore': ['jquery'],
        'backbone': ['underscore'],
        'core/core': ['underscore'],
        'core/errors': ['core/core'],
        'core/constants': ['core/core']
    }
});
```