# RequireJS fallback or checking for file existance

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I want to create a requirejs extension that would ***ideally*** look something like this:

```
var versions = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

define({
    load: function (name, req, onload, config) {
        var load = function (version) {
            try {
                req([name + '.' + versions[version]], function (value) {
                    onload(value);
                });
            } catch(ex) {
                if (version === versions.length - 1)
                    throw err;
                load(version + 1);
            }
        };

        load(0);
    });
});
```

Basically, I want to do this:

```
require(['plugin!my/file'], function (dep) {

});
```

And behind the scenes the logic should be:

> Check for my/file.one.js.  If it exists, return it.  If not...
>
> Check for my/file.two.js.  If it exists, return it.  If not...
>
> Check for my/file.three.js.  If it exists, return it.  If not...
>
> Throw

The problem seems to be that the errors for requesting files that don't exist thrown from `req` are async, so cannot be caught in this way.

Any recommendations for accomplishing this sort of functionality?

I found [requirejs fallbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12073768/requirejs-local-fallback-for-if-cdn-fails) but those only work for paths defined in your require config.  I want that exact same type of functionality for a standard require call.

I also found `require.defined` and `require.specified` but again, seems to only work on modules defined via the require.config or after having attempted to load a given module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me you'd want to use an [errback](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#errbacks). So something like this:

```
var versions = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

define({
    load: function (name, req, onload, config) {
        var load = function (version) {
            req([name + '.' + versions[version]], function (value) {
                onload(value);
            }, 
            function (err) {
                if (version === versions.length - 1)
                    throw err;
                load(version + 1);
            });
        };

        load(0);
    });
});
```

The errback is the second function passed to `req`. It will be called when loading the module fails.

Comment: This is perfect.  Didn't know the errback existed.  Thanks!

Comment: This still throws the error, if the file doesn't exists